# Jjimjilbang in Korea

Tags: south-korea, seoul

I’m going to South Korea next week. I saw this awesome [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKpIIPnXihw) on Youtube about a Jjimjilbang (spa/sauna) in South Korea. Unfortunately, it is located in Boryeong. I think I don’t have time to get there.

The ambience in the video looks amazing. I know there are many Jjimjilbang in Korea but can somebody recommend a similar ones in Seoul, Busan, or Jeju-do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't go to Boryeong just to visit JimJilBang.. there are hundreds and thousands of JimJilBang in SK.

In Seoul, I recommend 'Spa rex' which is located right next to 'DongDaeMoon history and culture park' subway station, exit 14. It's in 'good morning city' shopping mall.

Hope you enjoy your journey.

Answer (score 2):

There are hundreds, if not thousands, of Jiljilbangs in Seoul alone. I will recommend [Spa Lei](http://www.spalei.co.kr/) and [Dragon Hill Spa](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/south-korea/seoul/travel-tips-and-articles/75910). Both of them are open 24 hours and has websites in English as well as in Korean.

Spa Lei is a luxurious, ladies-only spa providing excellent services in an immaculate, stylish environment. The décor is earthy tones of brown, grey and orange using a range of materials including stained wood, marble and rock. Joseon-era furniture, candelabras towering over gilt mirrors and winding vines add an antique touch. The saunas include the much-loved pinewood, and you can hop from saltwater pool to ginseng, mineral and rose baths, plus there is a restaurant and café.

Dragon Hill Spa is spacious - spreading out over seven floors. In addition to outdoor baths, charcoal saunas, crystal salt rooms and ginseng and cedar baths, there is a golf driving range, cinema and rooftop garden with an Indian Barbeque Village. The outdoor unisex heated pool is perfect for families. There’s a sauna shaped like the pyramids but also a bamboo forest lit up with neon green lights. There’s always a smattering of foreigners – Russian models, Filipino migrant workers and Western English teachers. This place is a bit expensive but they usually have special packages on sale on different seasons.